# What Are Pokédex Current Recommendations Based Off?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

After completing the Galar Region Pokédex and the Isle of Armor Pokédex there is a new display that shows Current Recommendations:

> [image]

What are these current recommendations based off of?

The recommended regions seem random and they change. The Pokémon could just be weather related?

Answer (score 3):

After completing the dex you will receive a different set of current recommendations.

These current recommendations are based off of which Pokémon have a higher spawn rate.

[Blaines explains this in his video](https://youtu.be/wsFkEY1SK_c) where he mentions the

> much higher spawn rates

for current recommendations with a full dex.